# Problem when executing personnal JAR File in my program

Tags: java, image

I want to create a Java class that I use to export images. This class will be exported in `.JAR` file which will allow me to integrate it directly into another project by passing as input parameter the name of the file and in return I would have this image in `PNG` format.

That's what I tried:

```
package militarySymbolsLibrary;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class MainEntry {

    public static void main(String agrs[]) {


    }



    public static BufferedImage generateImage(String symbolCode) {

        File imageFile = new File("/pictures/SSGPU-------.png");

        BufferedImage image;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            image = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;
    }

}
```

Pictures are stocked in folder pictures like this treeview below:

`src
  MainEntry.java
pictures
  SSGPU-------.png`

Then I export this class in `.JAR` file, I add it to my other program, I pass a parameter (picture's name except for this test) and normally my class return `PNG` file. But I have an error telling me that the file path is not the rigth one.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: By putting a slash in front of the first directory/folder, you are specifying that the folder is at the root of the filesystem -- is that what you meant?

Comment: Images will be converted to [`embedded-resources`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) when you put them into a JAR file, so it's wise to start threating them as such. See these [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42449682/2180785), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34232097/2180785), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637076/2180785) and some [more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2180785+getResource) to guide you.

Comment: @Frakcool Ok thanks i will check that